# Creating to shared memory segments under the same name - returns an error?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, shared-memory

Given this code:

```
char * pathname; // some string 
int returnValue = shm_open(pathname, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, mode);  // create a shared memory object
```

If I do this: note - same pathname!)

```
int returnValue2 = shm_open(pathname, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, mode);  // create a shared memory object
```

I get no error, and the return value is okay (`0`).

Does it mean that I'm recreating a shared memory segment/object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just re-opening the existing shared memory segment.

> ```
> O_CREAT
> ```
>
> Create the shared memory object if it does not exist. (...)
>
> ```
> O_EXCL
> ```
>
> If  O_CREAT  was  also  specified, and a shared memory  object with the given name already exists, return an error.

(From the Linux [man shm_open](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/shm_open.3.html).)

Additionally, from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html) (a bit more explicit):

> ```
> O_CREAT
> ```
>
> If the shared memory object exists, this flag has no effect, except as noted under O_EXCL below. Otherwise, the shared memory object is created. (...)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the `shm_open()` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open):

> **Return Value**:
>   On success, `shm_open()` returns a nonnegative file descriptor. On failure, `shm_open()` returns -1.

Based on that, I would say that you have created and opened or opened an existing shared memory object.

Comment: How can I create the shared memory , and if the user tries to create with the same `pathname` then return `-1` , without keeping the `pathname` in some kind of a structure like a linked-list of `pathname`-s ? thanks

Comment: I think this is covered in the other answer that was posted, I believe what you have to do is add the `O_CREAT` flag. I'm not an expert on this though.